# jQuery Adding Extra Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jQuery Code which I'm using to show or hide a particular section from the page:

```
<script>
if(location.search == "?show=success"){
  $('.step, #step1').hide();
  $('.success').show();
  location.hash = 'ka?show=success';
}
if(location.search == "?show=successtwo"){
  $('.step, #step1, #FlowFour2').hide();
  $('.success-two').show();
  location.hash = 'ka?show=successtwo';
}
</script>
```

It actually works, but in the process also adds extra parameters to the final URL.

So if I access http://example.com/ka/?show=success, I get redirected to http://example.com/ka/?show=success#ka?show=success

Can someone help in this please?

Comment: The issue is because `location.hash` sets the fragment of the URL - ie. the part *after* the `#`. To do what you require you'll need to use `pushState`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method

Comment: Can you provide a small example on how to use this to achieve the above please :) ?

Comment: See the link I posted above, specifically: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Example_of_pushState()_method